# Font in messaging has became huge

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, sms, lg-g3

In the stock messaging app on my LG-G3 I have the following problem:

Suddenly, all my conversations is displayed with a font size that is incredibly large. This happened out of the blue. On the other hand, a lot of times when I have been speaking in my phone (and I do not speak for a long while) my cheek has navigated the phone into some app and possibly into some settings.

How do I make it like before? Preferrably at the same size as in the popup window  that pops up and dissapears when I get a sms.

I have not found a setting for the font size or that I should be able to set it using the volume key.

Comment: It's good that you have found the solution by yourself! Now, could you add some more details to the problem, like, is this the stock Messaging apps on LG G3? If not, what is the app?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer: pinch zoom!

Using the two finger gesture in the messaging app changes the font size on:

- texts
- smileys
- the "Enter message" field, default text as well as input text.

But not

- messages timestamp
- bubbles widths
- the menu
- the send button
- the paper clip icon

If I then close the app, using either triangle or circle, the setting will persist.

Comment: Again, could you add more detail to this answer? Not all Messaging apps have this feature, so perhaps you can add that "pinch zoom" is apparently a feature of this app.

Comment: I have to agree with Andrew: There's a general feature called "pinch to zoom", but that usually does not "stick"; as soon as you switch the activity/page/app, it gets reverted. So could you please [edit] your answer and describe step-by-step what you did to fix your issue?

Comment: This was exactly the issue for me. Pinch to zoom within Google messages was being persisted. Who on earth thought this was a good UX decision is beyond me...

Answer (score 1):

On some phones (including my Samsung Galaxy S4), the volume key enlarges and diminishes the text in messaging.  "Louder" makes it larger, "softer" is smaller.

Comment: Using the volume keys only changed the volume.

Comment: "On some phones" doesn't mean it'll work on *your* phone.

Comment: I thought your answer was written assuming that my phone could be one of those "some phones", but it is not. Thanks however and now I have found a solution!